# Get If Cookie has expired

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie that will expire in a given amount of time. When the cookie is active (i.e. not expired) a div will be displayed. Once the time has expired the div will not be displayed and never again be displayed.

The cookie needs to be set on first page load and the expire date set.

I don't think the cookie needs to ever be deleted because that would then cause the cookie to be recreated.

So I guess I need to somehow check if the cookie has expired, not if it still exist.  I can't find any information on how to check if a cookie has expired, only if it exist.

I'm new at cookies but here is my latest attempt:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("test=") >= 0) {

}
else {
    // set a new cookie
    expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime()+(2*60*1000)); // Two minutes

    // Date()'s toGMTSting() method will format the date correctly for a cookie
    document.cookie = "test=" + expiry.toGMTString() +"; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString() +"; path=/";

    if (document.cookie.indexOf("test=" + expiry.toGMTString() +"")){
        //stuff here 
    }  
}
```

I know it's probably way off.  Also I have js.cookie.js installed just in case I needed it.

Comment: Cookie is deleted when it expires. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: Save the time in the cookie and read it from the cookie later, instead of expiring the cookie.

Comment: when a cookie expires the browser drops it so all you do is check if cookie exists if it does not its expired

Comment: I haven't seen any cookies delete themselves after they expire.  They are still there with the expire date/time.  How can I save the time in a cookie?

Comment: Maybe if I set the cookie to expire in say a year but have the value for the cookie to say an hour? If this would work how could I check the cookie to see if the value has elapsed?